# How to replace the SharePoint root site template from classic team to modern team?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online, teamsite

I have created a SharePoint tenant. But the root site template type is the classic team.

How to replace my SharePoint root site template with the modern team from the classic team?

Answer (score 0):

**Please follow the steps:**

**STEP 1:MAKE SURE ROOT SITE IS NOT USED**

First, make sure that the current, classic root site and subsites (if any) are not used by anyone. If it is or was used, make sure all the content has been backed up and no one is synchronizing any libraries from the root site or its subsites to their computers (otherwise, when the old site is moved over to archival URL – more on this later) – it will cause sync issues.

**STEP 2: CREATE A MODERN SITE FIRST**

1.Navigate to either a SharePoint Admin Center or SharePoint Start Page and click on Create Site. Then choose Communication Site template

[image]

2.Give your site a name, click **Finish**

[image]

Note: This new site must be a **Team site (without an Office 365 Group)** or **Communication site**. It can’t be connected to an Office 365 group (the most common type of site in your environment).

**STEP 3: NAVIGATE TO THE SHAREPOINT ADMIN CENTER**

Navigate to the [SharePoint Admin Center](https://admin.microsoft.com/sharepoint?page=home&modern=true) >> **Active sites**

[image]

**STEP 4: REPLACE A CLASSIC ROOT SITE IN SHAREPOINT ONLINE WITH THE MODERN COMMUNICATION SITE**

1.Copy the URL of the Communication Site we created in Step2

2.Now click on the checkbox next to the root site (the one with just [domain.sharepoint.com] in the URL column, then choose **Replace site** from the top ribbon (you might need to click on three dots to get to that command)

[image]

3.On the next screen, paste the URL of the Communication Site from Step2, then click Save

[image]

4.And just after a few minutes, your site swap will be completed!

**Here is a good blog for your reference:**

- [How to replace a classic root site in SharePoint Online with a modern site](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-replace-a-classic-root-site-in-sharepoint-online-with-a-modern-site/)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-root-site - In addition, refer this as well.